# Saving the GUID in arcgis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

In my database of points with lat and long. After clipping the data to get only the ones in the specific state, my ID column that I had before disappeared. How can I clip my data and still keep the GUID that I had before?

I am clipping directly from Microsoft SQL server. On the server the GUID column is type [uniqueIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: is your new layer a FeatureClass?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: you should be able to right click on your featureClass, click on Manage and Add "Global ID's" in ArcCatalog

Comment: I don't see Manage as an option. I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Comment: I think I should also note that the GUID were not created by ArcGIS. The GUID was created elsewhere and I want to preserve that column when clipping the area that I need.

Comment: OK, your GUID are stored in which format (Int, Text, blob...)?

Comment: Rather than reply to requests for clarifications using more comments would you be able to use the edit button to revise your question, please?

Answer (score 2):

Global IDs are available in File Geodatabase, Personal Geodatabase and ArcSDE.  If you exported to a Shapefile you won't be able to create them.

[image: ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.2]

The other option if you only need to keep the value of the Global IDs for reference, you can copy them to a new text field before clipping.